# Create a Show/Hide Link - HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone help me with this problem? I am new using CSS/HTML.
I want to create a link div to hide and show its contents. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

## html

```
<a href="#" id="hideShow">My Title</a>
<div id="message" style="visibility:hidden; border: 1px solid #777; width: 400px; padding: 1%;">
    Blah Blah Blah Blah
</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $("#hide").toggle(
        function(){$("#message").show();},
        function(){$("#message").hide();},
});

</script>
```

Thanks...

Comment: First your jQuery procedure needs to be inside `$(document).ready(function(){...});` so that it runs when the page has loaded. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: "This question appears to be off-topic" - this is the kind of crap that makes me hate S.O. The whole point of asking questions is to get filled in on what you don't know. *incoming crap argument*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
$("#hideShow").click(function(){
   $("#message").toggle();
});
```

**Note**: Your id of "My Title" a tag is `hideShow` & not `hide`, also use `display:none` instead of `visibility: hidden;`.

```js
$("#hideShow").click(function() { $("#message").toggle(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="hideShow">My Title</a>
<div id="message" style="display:none; border: 1px solid #777; width: 400px; padding: 1%;">
    Blah Blah Blah Blah
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it on mouse click , you can do like so. Where #hide would be the ID of the "button" or element you want to click for the #message to either show or hide.

```
    $("#hideShow").click(function() {
        $("#message").toggle();
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

If you just want it to happen automatically once your page loads without clicking a button, you can do like so:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#message").show(4000);
        $("#message").hide(3000);
    });
```

4000 and 3000 are equal to 4 seconds and 3 seconds respectively. It is the amount of time it takes to fully show then fully hide. Adjust however you like.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
$("#hideShow").click(function () {
    $("#message").toggle();
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/669k4/

Changed visibility:none to display:none.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This:

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hide_show").click(function() {
         $("#message").toggle();
       });
    });
</script>

<a href="#"  id="hide_show" title="toggle(show/hide)">My Title</a>
<div id="message" style=" display:none; border: 1px solid #777; width: 400px; padding: 1%;">
    Blah Blah Blah Blah
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<a href="#" id="hideShow">My Title</a>
<div id="message" style="display:none; border: 1px solid #777; width: 400px; padding: 1%;">
  Blah Blah Blah Blah
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){
  $("a#hideShow").bind("click", function(){
    $("#message").toggle();
 });
});
</script>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/6KRgn/5/

Answer (score 0):

You are showing/hideing your div based on the toggle event of something you don't even define "$("#hide")" there is not an element with id = "hide".

You have to think about what you want, if you want to show/hide message based on click in your link, you can something like this :

```
$("#hideShow").click(function(){
   $("#message").toggle();
});
```